# Dismiss a curled page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, page-curl

From my main view, i have a button that when pressed triggers a modal segue with curl effects, which in turn shows 3 buttons, which all have modal segues. When any of these buttons are pressed, they show another view, but i can't seem to get rid of the curled view. Any help is appreciated to get rid of the curled view before loading the new view.

Good day!

Comment: the answer is really that you shouldn't use a non-page-curl modal view controller nested under a page-curl modal view controller, so you can either choose a different kind of modal view transition besides curl for the first, or live with one and all modal and nested modal view controllers having the page-curl showing.

Answer (score 0):

If it's modal, you can just call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in the view's class you want to dismiss.

Comment: the way i read his question, i don't think this is going to help.  i think he is trying to go from the modal view controller that he's in to a nested modal view controller.  if his code calls dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:, he will end up in the parentViewController.  and since he's attempting to use segues, he's not trying to use presentViewController: to get into the nested modal view controller.

Comment: Yeah, rereading it it seems like that's what will happen, he's either going to have to do something like what you said in your comment to the question or make that first view appear using a custom segue so he can do the animation he requires.

Answer (score 0):

since ios5 `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is deprecated, use this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
       //completion or NULL
 }];
```

Comment: as with Matt S's answer … the way i read his question, i don't think this is going to help. i think he is trying to go from the modal view controller that he's in to a nested modal view controller.  calling dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: is going to have the same problem as dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: … namely, he will end up in the parentViewController. and since he's attempting to use segues, he's not trying to use presentViewController: to get into the nested modal view controller.  so clicking on a button will go the opposite way he desires with his segues.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[self.flipViewOneController.view removeFromSuperview];
```